# Battery percentage jumps down to 6% from 50% or 60%?

Tags: laptop, power-management, indicator, battery

So, as the title says, I have checked Power Stats in Ubuntu and Energy when Full and Energy (design) are the same which is 37.2 Wh but the percentage is funny with actual battery life left in my laptop's 6 cell battery.

I can charge up to 100% but around 50 or 60%, It just completely drops to 6% with the OSD telling me about the low percentage

Below is Power Stat on the Battery for proof.[image]

Comment: What does your capacity read as? It's the line right below Percentage, where your window cuts off.

Comment: capacity is 100.0% and Technology is Lithium Ion

Comment: Now, I'm getting even weirder behavior from the battery, my laptop shutoff before 0% hit and when I came back it was 13% then I got 45% after I plugged it in. The battery itself isn't even a year old yet and brand new, I did have a 9 cell before. Should I leave it plugged in after the power meter hits 100% because it went from 12% and rocketed up to 43% in a short time frame. and now 75% in a short time frame from 43%

Comment: Here are a few questions that might help us:

  1. What version of Ubuntu?

  2. What is the model of the laptop?

  3. When did this start happening? Or what has changed recently that might have caused this?

Comment: Well, to anwser them in order, 1. Ubuntu 15.04 64-Bit 2. HP Envy dv6-7213NR 3. It started to happen recently after I got my laptop back from HP for repairs for a LCD display with horizontal lines that showed up with pressure on the left side, fixed now but they didn't replace the battery with a new one, made sure of that. and 4. It's draining almost normal now but it drains like this. 100% 97% 96% 94% 92% 91% but before was like 100% 95% 86% 60%

Comment: So, I guess I'm stuck with this behavior then since no one knows how to fix it